# Using tensorflow batch normalization stalls loss decrease

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I'm using tensorflow version r0.11
I'm trying to use the batch normalization (tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm()) in a conv net. As a headstart, I followed the discussions made in the following github [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1122). It seems that 'is_training', 'reuse' and 'updates_collections' flags are still confusing (in usage), partly because of the lack of good use cases. However, my problem is that the loss is not decreasing if I add batch norm layer.

I framed the code following the structure as in CIFAR. And I am running it in a multi-gpu fashion (for training). I have one script for training (similar to cifar10_multigpu.py) and one for testing (similar to cifar10_eval.py).

```
for i in xrange(all_flags.num_gpus): # Number of GPUs is 2
    with tf.device('/gpu:%d' % i):
        with tf.name_scope('%s_%d' % (all_flags.TOWER_NAME, i)) as scope:
            # Calculate the loss for one tower of the model. This  function
            # constructs the entire model but shares the variables across all
            # towers.
            loss = _tower_loss(inputs[i], labels[i], scope) 

            # Reuse variables for the next tower. This line makes it possible
            tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()

            # More stuff happening like compute_gradients (inside gpus loop),
            # averaging gradients (outside gpus loop), applying them (outside
            # gpus loop)
```

The inference/model building happens within (a nested function in) the function _tower_loss. (below is an example of the function, in reality I use more layers and neurons).

```
def inference(inputs): #(This gets called from _tower_loss())
    # conv1
    with tf.variable_scope('conv1') as scope:
        kernel = # define kernel
        conv = tf.nn.conv2d(inputs, kernel, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
        biases = _variable_on_gpu('biases', [64], tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
        preactivation = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
        # ReLU.
        conv1 = tf.nn.relu(preactivation, name=scope.name)

    # pool1
    pool1 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv1, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                           strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME', name='pool1')

    # Similarly more conv+pool and then fcs and finally logits
    return logits
```

I want to perform batch nomalization. So I passed in an additional placeholder input argument inside my '_tower_loss' as well as 'inference' functions.

```
def inference(inputs, is_training):
    # BN1
    with tf.variable_scope('norm0') as scope:
        # Note that I'm using the dafault for 'updates_collections'
        # which is None
        norm0 = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(inputs, is_training=is_training,
                scope=scope, reuse=None)

    # conv1
    with tf.variable_scope('conv1') as scope:
        kernel = # define kernel
        conv = tf.nn.conv2d(norm0, kernel, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
        # Rest is same
```

I also added normalization layers in the couple of fc layers

In the train code the instructions go like this
...

```
variable_averages = tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(0.9999, global_step)
variables_averages_op = variable_averages.apply(tf.trainable_variables())

train_op = tf.group(apply_gradient_op, variables_averages_op)
update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS) # Line A
```

...

```
sess.run([train_op, loss, update_ops],feed_dict={is_training: True}) # Line B
```

...

When Batch normalization is not there, Line A is not there and in Line B, 'update_ops' is run in the session.

What I'm seeing is that when batch normalization is not used loss starts at aorund 6.5 and consistently decreases to near 0, but when I'm using batch normalization loss does not decrease after 2 or 3 hundred (minibatch) iterations and gets stuck at around 5.5 or so. Speedwise, I'd say the performance is same. I'm not sure what is the issue. I tried with different learning rate (I'm using Adam optimizer) with no effect. I'm not sure whether 'variables_averages_op' along with 'update_ops' is messing things up. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: hope this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43234667/tf-layers-batch-normalization-large-test-error