# tf.layers.batch_normalization large test error

Tags: batch-normalization

I'm trying to use batch normalization. I tried to use  tf.layers.batch_normalization on a simple conv net for mnist.

I get high accuracy for train step (>98%) but very low test accuracy (<50%). I tried to change momentum values (I tried 0.8,0.9,0.99,0.999) and to play to with batch sizes but it always behaves basically the same way. I train it on 20k iterations.

my code

```
# Input placeholders
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784], name='x-input')
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10], name='y-input')
is_training = tf.placeholder(tf.bool)

# inut layer
input_layer = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 28, 28, 1])
with tf.name_scope('conv1'):
    #Convlution #1 ([5,5] : [28x28x1]->[28x28x6])
    conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(
        inputs=input_layer,
        filters=6,
        kernel_size=[5, 5],
        padding="same",
        activation=None
    )   

    #Batch Norm #1
    conv1_bn = tf.layers.batch_normalization(
        inputs=conv1,
        axis=-1,
        momentum=0.9,
        epsilon=0.001,
        center=True,
        scale=True,
        training = is_training,
        name='conv1_bn'
    )

    #apply relu
    conv1_bn_relu = tf.nn.relu(conv1_bn)
    #apply pool ([2,2] : [28x28x6]->[14X14X6])
    maxpool1=tf.layers.max_pooling2d(
        inputs=conv1_bn_relu,
        pool_size=[2,2],
        strides=2,
        padding="valid"
    )

with tf.name_scope('conv2'):
    #convolution #2 ([5x5] : [14x14x6]->[14x14x16]
    conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(
        inputs=maxpool1,
        filters=16,
        kernel_size=[5, 5],
        padding="same",
        activation=None
    )   

    #Batch Norm #2
    conv2_bn = tf.layers.batch_normalization(
        inputs=conv2,
        axis=-1,
        momentum=0.999,
        epsilon=0.001,
        center=True,
        scale=True,
        training = is_training
    )

    #apply relu
    conv2_bn_relu = tf.nn.relu(conv2_bn)
    #maxpool2 ([2,2] : [14x14x16]->[7x7x16]
    maxpool2=tf.layers.max_pooling2d(
        inputs=conv2_bn_relu,
        pool_size=[2,2],
        strides=2,
        padding="valid"
    )

#fully connected 1 [7*7*16 = 784 -> 120]
maxpool2_flat=tf.reshape(maxpool2,[-1,7*7*16])
fc1 = tf.layers.dense(
    inputs=maxpool2_flat,
    units=120,
    activation=None
)

#Batch Norm #2
fc1_bn = tf.layers.batch_normalization(
    inputs=fc1,
    axis=-1,
    momentum=0.999,
    epsilon=0.001,
    center=True,
    scale=True,
    training = is_training
)
#apply reliu

fc1_bn_relu = tf.nn.relu(fc1_bn)

#fully connected 2 [120-> 84]
fc2 = tf.layers.dense(
    inputs=fc1_bn_relu,
    units=84,
    activation=None
)

#apply relu
fc2_bn_relu = tf.nn.relu(fc2)

#fully connected 3 [84->10]. Output layer with softmax
y = tf.layers.dense(
    inputs=fc2_bn_relu,
    units=10,
    activation=None
)

#loss
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y))
tf.summary.scalar('cross entropy', cross_entropy)

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
tf.summary.scalar('accuracy',accuracy)

#merge summaries and init train writer
sess = tf.Session()
merged = tf.summary.merge_all()
train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(log_dir + '/train' ,sess.graph)
test_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(log_dir + '/test') 
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)

with sess.as_default():
    def get_variables_values():
        variables = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES)
        values = {}
        for variable in variables:
            values[variable.name[:-2]] = sess.run(variable, feed_dict={
                x:batch[0], y_:batch[1], is_training:True
                })
        return values


    for i in range(t_iter):
        batch = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
        if i%100 == 0: #test-set summary
            print('####################################')
            values = get_variables_values()
            print('moving variance is:')
            print(values["conv1_bn/moving_variance"])
            print('moving mean is:')
            print(values["conv1_bn/moving_mean"])
            print('gamma is:')
            print(values["conv1_bn/gamma/Adam"])
            print('beta is:')
            print(values["conv1_bn/beta/Adam"])
            summary, acc = sess.run([merged,accuracy], feed_dict={
                x:mnist.test.images, y_:mnist.test.labels, is_training:False

            })

        else:
            summary, _ = sess.run([merged,train_step], feed_dict={
                x:batch[0], y_:batch[1], is_training:True
            })
            if i%10 == 0:
                train_writer.add_summary(summary,i)
```

I think the problem is that that the moving_mean/var is not being updated.
I print the moving_mean/var during the run and I get:
moving variance is:
[ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
moving mean is:
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
gamma is:
[-0.00055969  0.00164391  0.00163301 -0.00206227 -0.00011434 -0.00070161]
beta is:
[-0.00232835 -0.00040769  0.00114277 -0.0025414  -0.00049697  0.00221556]

Anyone has any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, MrG, could you show me your test code? I have the same problem as you, and always predict constant using tf.layers.batch_normalization.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The operations which `tf.layers.batch_normalization` adds to update mean and variance don't automatically get added as dependencies of the train operation - so if you don't do anything extra, they never get run.
 (Unfortunately, the documentation doesn't currently mention this. I'm opening an issue about it.)

Luckily, the update operations are easy to get at, since they're added to the `tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS` collection. Then you can either run the extra operations manually:

```py
extra_update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
sess.run([train_op, extra_update_ops], ...)
```

Or add them as dependencies of your training operation, and then just run your training operation as normal:

```py
extra_update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
with tf.control_dependencies(extra_update_ops):
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)
...
sess.run([train_op], ...)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.. I saw posts detailing similar approach for when batch norm was still in contrib -- I made a mistake of thinking it was "fixed" when they migrated to tf.layers
Is there any reason that you would not make updating mean and variance default behaviour?

Comment: I agree, it's a little inconvenient. I suspect it might be a similar situation as with summary ops: the data flow through the graph to the loss function simply doesn't depend on these operations, so they have to be invoked separately.

Comment: Thank you! Would be very helpful if TF documentation noted this.

Comment: Do you have to do anything special when saving and restoring the model? I have a model which performs much worse once it has been saved and evaluated later after being restored.