# Why is LayerNormBasicLSTMCell much slower and less accurate than LSTMCell?

Tags: tensorflow, normalization, lstm

I recently found that LayerNormBasicLSTMCell is a version of LSTM with Layer Normalization and dropout implemented. Therefore, I replaced the my original code using LSTMCell with LayerNormBasicLSTMCell. Not only did this change reduce the test accuracy from ~96% to ~92%, it took much longer time (~33 hours) to train (original training time is ~6 hours). All parameters are the same: number of epochs (10), number of stacked layers (3), number of hidden vector size (250), drop out keep prob (0.5), ... The hardware is also the same.

My question is: What did I do wrong here?

My original model (using LSTMCell):

```
# Batch normalization of the raw input
tf_b_VCCs_AMs_BN1 = tf.layers.batch_normalization(
    tf_b_VCCs_AMs, # the input vector, size [#batches, #time_steps, 2]
    axis=-1, # axis that should be normalized 
    training=Flg_training, # Flg_training = True during training, and False during test
    trainable=True,
    name="Inputs_BN"
    )

# Bidirectional dynamic stacked LSTM

##### The part I changed in the new model (start) #####
dropcells = []
for iiLyr in range(3):
    cell_iiLyr = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_units=250, state_is_tuple=True)
    dropcells.append(tf.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(cell=cell_iiLyr, output_keep_prob=0.5))
##### The part I changed in the new model (end) #####

MultiLyr_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell(cells=dropcells, state_is_tuple=True)

outputs, states  = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(
    cell_fw=MultiLyr_cell, 
    cell_bw=MultiLyr_cell,
    dtype=tf.float32,
    sequence_length=tf_b_lens, # the actual lengths of the input sequences (tf_b_VCCs_AMs_BN1)
    inputs=tf_b_VCCs_AMs_BN1,
    scope = "BiLSTM"
    )
```

My new model (using LayerNormBasicLSTMCell):

```
...
dropcells = []
for iiLyr in range(3):
    cell_iiLyr = tf.contrib.rnn.LayerNormBasicLSTMCell(
        num_units=250,
        forget_bias=1.0,
        activation=tf.tanh,
        layer_norm=True,
        norm_gain=1.0,
        norm_shift=0.0,
        dropout_keep_prob=0.5
        )
    dropcells.append(cell_iiLyr)
...
```

Comment: A thought: Could [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43234667/tf-layers-batch-normalization-large-test-error](this) be the issue? 

It appears that the mean and variance do not get updated automatically in `tf.layers.batch_normalization`. I wonder if `tf.contrib.rnn.LayerNormBasicLSTMCell ` suffers the same problem.

Comment: @FariborzGhavamian, I used the second method for both normalization functions (i.e. `update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)` and `with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):` ...).

Comment: About the training time: I found this on the tensorflow website: https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_guide#common_fused_ops. You can turn on a parameter called `fused` and get a 12%-30% speed up.

Comment: @FariborzGhavamian, thanks for the guide link. I will read through the entire guide on performance. They all seem very useful. I will give them (including the parameter `fused`) a try.

Comment: @FariborzGhavamian, the fused parameter is related to batch_normalization and has nothing to do with layer_normalization.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps `dropout_keep_prob` should be assigned a placeholder instead of a constant value. Try to assign `0.5` at training and `1.0` at inference. Just a guess.

Comment: This will definitely be required. Dropout obviously needs to be off during evaluation, and the cell has no way of knowing which mode it is in, so you need to tell it by setting `dropout_keep_prob` to 1.0 during evaluation.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning the value for `dropout_keep_prob` should be different for training and test. The actual code has it assigned by a mode specific value.

Answer (score 2):

About the training time: I came across this blog post: http://olavnymoen.com/2016/07/07/rnn-batch-normalization. See the last figure. The batch normalized lstm was more than 3 times slower than the vanilla lstm. The writer argues that the reason is the batch statistics computation.

About the accuracy: I have no idea.

Comment: I didn't read the post very carefully, I think the post is talking about Batch Normalization rather than Layer Normalization (the one in the question)?

Comment: Yes, the post is about the batch normalization. But the common ground between that and the layer normalization is computation of statistics (mean and variance). Granted that the statistics are computed based on different data (BN: over batch, LN: over layers), nevertheless it seems to be an additional computation cost.

Comment: I don't understand why simple calculation of statistics (mean or variance) costs that much time (especially with GPU).

Answer (score 1):

Batch normalization and layer normalization don't simply normalize the input distribution over a minibatch, they also add the new learnable variables beta and gamma. That's a scalar for each each dimension of every input, so four inputs times two times the dimensionality of the input.

I assume it's this large number of new trainable variables that accounts for the slowdown.

By the way, if you turn off `layer_norm` it speeds up massively, so that would support the assumption that it's the layer normalization that's the issue.

Comment: In the litterature, layer normalization (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.06450.pdf )  does indeed speed-up the training time. So saying turning the layer_norm off speeds up massively is quite wrong.

Comment: I meant it speeds up the time a single batch takes. Of course turning it on might mean that the loss decreases faster, making the total time to reach a certain loss lower.