# How to correctly use the tf.layers.batch_normalization() in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, batch-normalization

I'm confused by the `tf.layers.batch_normalization` in tensorflow.

My code is as follows:

```py
def my_net(x, num_classes, phase_train, scope):
    x = tf.layers.conv2d(...)
    x = tf.layers.batch_normalization(x, training=phase_train)
    x = tf.nn.relu(x) 
    x = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(...)

    # some other staffs
    ...

    # return 
    return x

def train():
    phase_train = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, name='phase_train')
    image_node = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[batch_size, HEIGHT, WIDTH, 3])
    images, labels = data_loader(train_set)
    val_images, val_labels = data_loader(validation_set)
    prediction_op = my_net(image_node, num_classes=2,phase_train=phase_train, scope='Branch1')

    loss_op = loss(...)
    # some other staffs
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(base_learning_rate)
    update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
    with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
        train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss=total_loss, global_step=global_step)
    sess = ...
    coord = ...
    while not coord.should_stop():
        image_batch, label_batch = sess.run([images, labels])
        _,loss_value= sess.run([train_op,loss_op], feed_dict={image_node:image_batch,label_node:label_batch,phase_train:True})

        step = step+1

        if step==NUM_TRAIN_SAMPLES:
            for _ in range(NUM_VAL_SAMPLES/batch_size):
                image_batch, label_batch = sess.run([val_images, val_labels])
                prediction_batch = sess.run([prediction_op], feed_dict={image_node:image_batch,label_node:label_batch,phase_train:False})
            val_accuracy = compute_accuracy(...)


def test():
    phase_train = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, name='phase_train')
    image_node = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[batch_size, HEIGHT, WIDTH, 3])
    test_images, test_labels = data_loader(test_set)
    prediction_op = my_net(image_node, num_classes=2,phase_train=phase_train, scope='Branch1')

    # some staff to load the trained weights to the graph
    saver.restore(...)

    for _ in range(NUM_TEST_SAMPLES/batch_size):
        image_batch, label_batch = sess.run([test_images, test_labels])
        prediction_batch = sess.run([prediction_op], feed_dict={image_node:image_batch,label_node:label_batch,phase_train:False})
    test_accuracy = compute_accuracy(...)
```

The training seems to work well and the `val_accuracy` is reasonable (say `0.70`). The problem is: when I tried to use the trained model to do test (i.e., the `test` function), if the `phase_train` is set to `False`, the `test_accuracy` is very low (say, `0.000270`), but when the `phase_train` is set to `True`, the `test_accuracy` seems right (say `0.69`).

As far as I understood, the `phase_train` should be `False` in testing stage, right?
I'm not sure what the problem is. Do I misunderstand the batch normalization?

Comment: Related: [tf.layers.batch_normalization large test error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43234667/tf-layers-batch-normalization-large-test-error)

Comment: Hi @Drop, thanks for your comment. Yeah, I've added the dependency of `update_ops` in the `train` function. But the error still exists.

Comment: Setting `training=False` is correct. The problem might not lie with batch normalization. Are you sure you're loading the model checkpoints correctly?

Comment: Hi,@KathyWu, thanks for commment. Yeah, I think the loading is right. Because I also tried the model without BN. The model is loaded correctly and the prediction is reasonable. And for the `tf.layers.batch_normalization` layer, it has two parameters: `beta` and `gamma`. I also loaded the `scopt/batch_normalization_1/beta:0` and the `scope/batch_normalization_1/gamma:0` when using BN. The problem is when I set the `phase_train` to `True`, the prediction in the testing stage is reasonable. But in general, the `phase_train` should be `False`.

Comment: @mining After I added `... with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops): ...`, the `phase_train = False` works correctly when test stage.

Comment: Hi, @Tom, thanks a lot for your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

This may be some bug in your code, or just overfitting. If you evaluate on train data, is the accuracy as high as during training, or not?
If the problem was with batch norm, then the train error would be higher without training then in training mode. 
If the problem is overfitting, then the batch norm probably did not cause that and the root cause is elsewhere.